# ltxmisc could not be installed (error)

Tags: errors

I am having some problems with the following minimal code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{adjustbox}

\begin{document}
    hello world
\end{document}
```

And I tried compiling with pdflatex and xelatex (not simultaneously), via command prompt. But it keeps trying to install `ltxmisc` (and fails), even though I already have it installed. Is this a bug?

I am on Windows 10, 64 bit, MikTeX.

Log:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.19 (MiKTeX 2.9.6670 64-bit)
entering extended mode
(document.tex
LaTeX2e <2018-04-01> patch level 3
Babel <3.18> and hyphenation patterns for 75 language(s) loaded.
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\article.cls"
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\size10.clo"))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\adjustbox\adjustbox.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\xkeyval\xkeyval.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\xkeyval\xkeyval.tex"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\xkeyval\xkvutils.tex"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\xkeyval\keyval.tex"))))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\adjustbox\adjcalc.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\adjustbox\trimclip.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\graphicx.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\graphics.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\trig.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics-cfg\graphics.cfg")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics-def\pdftex.def")))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\collectbox\collectbox.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\adjustbox\tc-pdftex.def"))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\ifoddpage\ifoddpage.sty")
======================================================================
starting package maintenance...
installation directory: "C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9"
package repository: ftp://mirror.ox.ac.uk/sites/ctan.org/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/
visiting repository ftp://mirror.ox.ac.uk/sites/ctan.org/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/...
repository type: remote package repository
loading lightweight database...
downloading ftp://mirror.ox.ac.uk/sites/ctan.org/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/miktex-zzdb1-2.9.tar.lzma...
177070 bytes, 153.30 KB/Sec
lightweight database digest: 4c0605cf53b263d2fd3caf876df2daec
going to download 23515 bytes
going to install 18 file(s) (1 package(s))
downloading ftp://mirror.ox.ac.uk/sites/ctan.org/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/ltxmisc.tar.lzma...
23515 bytes, 168.85 KB/Sec
extracting files from ltxmisc.tar.lzma...

Unfortunately, the package ltxmisc could not be installed.Please check the log file:
C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/miktex/log/pdflatex.log
======================================================================
)
No file document.aux.
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\context\base\supp-pdf.mkii"
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
) ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\oberdiek\epstopdf-base.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\infwarerr.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\oberdiek\grfext.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\kvdefinekeys.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\ltxcmds.sty")))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\oberdiek\kvoptions.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\kvsetkeys.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\etexcmds.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\ifluatex.sty"))))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\pdftexcmds.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\ifpdf.sty"))) [1{C:/Users/us
er/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/pdftex/config/pdftex.map}] (document.aux) )<C:/Prog
ram Files/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb>
Output written on document.pdf (1 page, 11892 bytes).
Transcript written on document.log.
```

Proof that `ltxmisc` is already installed:

[image: pic]

Comment: Try if it helps if you sychronize the package  database in the console.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thanks for the suggestion, but nope, didn't help. No further updates on MikTeX console -- and still asking to install ltxmisc during compilation.

Comment: I didn't say update. I wrote "synchronize". Do you know what this mean? And did you do it with both console versions (admin and user)?

Comment: I know there was a synchronize option in past versions of Miktex (before the console). I don’t see one here. Sorry, where can I find it? I only did with admin (with the “Restart in Admin mode) option of the console when you first start it up.

Comment: you find in the task menu, it is called "update package database" or something like this. And do it with both console versions.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I did what is suggested -- All is well now, the only new package I installed via the console was `babel`. Then `varwidth` during compilation. I'll close the question, thanks for your help!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because solved in comments.